# dmg2img Image is corrupt

Tags: disk-image

Okay, so I have a .dmg file I want to convert to .img
It's stored in my home directory so I type:

```
dmg2img image.dmg image.img
```

(The image is actually called image)

Then I get:

```
caitlan@caitlan-iMac:~$ dmg2img image.dmg image.img

dmg2img v1.6.2 is derived from dmg2iso by vu1tur (to@vu1tur.eu.org)

ERROR: dmg image is corrupted
```

What can I do? Can I fix this? Could I use a different program to do the conversion? I'm 90% sure the image isn't corrupted

Comment: Are you using full path?

Comment: I have the same problem on [this download](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc7860dw_all&os=132&dlid=dlf005024_000&flang=4&type3=318). I think OS X 10.9 `.dmg` images are not supported by the current dmg2img tool.

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this issue recently, and found a workaround.  Posting it here, for anyone else who has this problem.

As it so happens, for some use cases, dmg = img.  For example, if you want to write a MacOS installer dmg to a USB drive, in Linux, you can do this:

```
dd if=image.dmg of=/dev/myusbdrive
```

(Replace "myusbdrive" with the device name of your USB drive, such as "sde".)

If all you want to do is change the file extension, you can just move/rename it:

```
mv image.dmg image.img
```

With both of these methods, the partition schema and filesystems of the new image or device will be the same as the old image or device (GPT partition table with a single HFS+ filesystem, for example).

I know that this doesn't directly address how to get dmg2img working (it seems to be a bug), but hopefully, this will help someone out of a bind, in the future.

Answer (score 0):

the image may be password-protected. If this is the case I don't know if img2dmg is able to handle the situation.

Comment: Unlikely for a publicly distributed software package.